# How can I return something from HashMap.get’s None case?

Tags: rust

I'm wondering with the best practice to handle the `None` result in getting values from a `HashMap`. Given I have a simple function:

```
pub fn get_value(&self, value: String) -> &String {
```

One could get the value from the `HashMap` with `unwrap`:

```
my_map.get(&"hello".to_string()).unwrap()
```

But I don’t want it to panic if it gets `None`. What else can I do?

```
match self.os_config.get(&value) {
    Some(val) => return &val,
    None =>  //?? cannot return a String::new().. as it is temporal?
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For starters, `&String` is a type that should never exist in a signature; you should take the more general `&str`. `String` is specifically an owned string, while `&str` is a string slice. Because `String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`, `&String` coerces to `&str`.

When dealing with hash map keys, you should also take `&str` rather than `&String`, and you should avoid taking `String` if all you need is `&str`; you don’t need to consume the string. You can index a `HashMap<String, _>` with `&str` just fine.

The type of a string literal is `&'static str`; `&'static str` will quite happily coerce to `&'a str` for any `'a`, so you can quite happily use an empty string literal on the `None` branch. Here’s the result:

```
pub fn get_value(&self, value: &str) -> &str {
    match self.os_config.get(value) {
        Some(val) => val,
        None => "",
    }
}
```

This can also be written using the handy [`unwrap_or`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) method:

```
pub fn get_value(&self, value: &str) -> &str {
    self.os_config.get(value).unwrap_or("")
}
```

For this reason, returning an `Option<&str>` is perhaps not so tedious; other places can add `.unwrap_or("")` if they want to. Of course, it all depends on the desired semantics.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return an arbitrary type or result, such that you can't use a `'static` reference, you can return a `Cow` type from the function.

A simple demo is at [Holy std::borrow::Cow!](https://llogiq.github.io/2015/07/09/cow.html), but you basically just have to wrap it in a `Cow::Borrowed` normally and a `Cow::Owned` for the error case.

Comment: Holy Cow, I've been quoted here. ;-) Feel free to copy the example here. I'll try to make sure the link won't go stale, but one never knows.